# Every Infinite bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$ has a limit point

Tags: real-analysis

---

I am aware a set is Bounded if it has both upper and Lower bound and i know what a Limit point of a set is but i am finding it hard to show that If S $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$  be a bounded infinite set, then S' $\neq \emptyset$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If S is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, then it has a supremum.

Comment: or inf, if bounded below, or both, but does not matter

Answer (score 1):

There's a little trick to this one.

Let
$$
T = \{x\in\mathbb R\;\colon\;x\le y\textrm{ for infinitely many $y\in S$}\}
$$

Prove that $T$ is non-empty and bounded above.  That means that $T$ has a supremum $t$.  Now see if you can find anything interesting about $t$.